# In XCode 4.5.2 there's no auto @synthesize-ing properties defined in the interface

Tags: xcode

Is there any way getting those back?
I'm following some video tutorials where dragging a text field to the h file creates a property and a @synthesize in the m file. In xcode 4.5.2 the @synthesize are not created. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: In new Xcode the synthesize is not needed anymore. As long as the property is defined you directly have access to the underscore variable. property aProp. The compiler automatically generates synthesize aProp = _aProp. It means the accessors and mutators (getters and setters in other languages) are automatically generated. In the case you want to write your own, you'll have to synthesize manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XCode 4.5.2 it's not mandatory, but you can create them. If no `@synthesize` there it means `@synthesize myProp = _myProp;`

Comment: ... except when you implement accessors or use `@dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 4.5 contains a newer version of clang that synthesizes by default. The `@synthesize` directive is not needed any more.

Comment: ... unless you build for 32-bit, which then fails.

Comment: @trojanfoe ... at least on Mac OS (where a legacy and a modern runtime exists). But that should not too often be an issue any more, nowadays.

Comment: Agreed.  It's an issue for me though, as I want to support 10.{6,7,8} {32,64}-bit in my App.